# How do I put things in my RequestBody for my POST Method to find?

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

I am *very* new to ASP.NET Core, C#, and RESTful APIs. I'm trying to create a simple practice application right now to practice the different REST commands. The "database" I am working with is a List of objects that have a Name, Age, and Weight.

Currently I am trying to implement a POST method. I could potentially use a [FromQuery] in order to get the data I need for creating the new object and adding it. However, I think it would be better to access it FromBody, especially if I want to add more fields later on.

I don't quite understand/know how I would be able to put stuff/ask the user (??) for data for this in the body. I think I grasp that, when the URL is called, it parses through whatever is in the body of the page/the returned .json and finds it that way, but I don't know how to populate this in the first place.

So far this is just my code for the POST:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult<List<Objects>> Post([FromQuery] String NewName, [FromQuery] int NewAge, [FromQuery] double NewWeight)
        {
            return MyList.AddItem(NewName, NewAge, NewWeight);

        }
```

I would love any descriptions on how this works or how I can make this happen...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Create a model that holds all the required data

```
public class NewModel {
    public String NewName { get; set; }
    public int NewAge { get; set; }
    public double NewWeight { get; set; }
}
```

update the action to expect that data and annotate it with `[FromBody]`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<MyModelType> Post([FromBody] NewModel data) {
    if (ModelState.IsValid) {
        var model = MyList.AddItem(data.NewName, data.NewAge, data.NewWeight);
        return model;
    }
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

Consumers of your service would then post a request with the required data in the body of the request and the model binder should populate the model in the controller action.